# How To fix failed to load resource in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, console, console.log

I'm working on a weather app and following a tutorial from Dev Ed on youtube. I'm supposed to be getting some information in the console log but instead, I get this error, Failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 400. How do I remove this syntax error and what seems to be the reason for it?
Thanks, Love2Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Local Weather</title>
 <script>
 window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  //Asks user location
  let long;
  let lat;
  
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
    long = position.coords.longitude;
    lat = position.coords.latidute;
    
    const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    const api =`${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/217e0a6f0942213d0c3e6990a8b626f3/${lat},${long}`;
    //Catches weather info from website
   fetch(api)
   .then(response => {
    return response.json();
   })
   .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
   });
   
  });
  }
 });

 </script>
<style>
@media screen and (min-width:1px) and (max-width:1365px) {
    ...
}
@media screen and (min-width:1366px) {
    ...
}
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
 height:100vh;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 flex-direction:column;
 align-items:center;
 background:linear-gradient(rgb(47,150,163), rgb(48,62,143));
 font-family:sans-serif;
 color:white;
 
}
.location, .temperature{
 height:30vh;
 width:50%;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-around;
 align-items:center;
 
}
.temperature{
flex-direction:column;
}
.degree-section{
 display:flex;
 align-center:center;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.degree-section span{
 margin:10px;
 font-size:30px;
 
}
.degree-section h2{
 font-size:35px;
 position:relative;
 top:5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="location">
<h1 class="location-timezone">Timezone</h1>
<p>Icon</p>
</div>
<div class="temperature">
<div class="degree-section">
<h2 class="temperature-degree">34</h2>
<span>F</span>
</div>
<div class="temperature-description">It's cold
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

Comment: `const api =`${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/217e0a6f0942213d0c3e6990a8b626f3/${lat},${long}`;` <<<< If `proxy` is a full URL, placing it in front of another full URL doesn't seem right.

Comment: I think your params might be wrong. When I run your code using static lat/long variables that i got from https://www.latlong.net/ it works just fine. Can you add/show your full URL?